# Usage of Articles(definite vs indefinte)

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, articles

"Find the area of a triangle whose side is 3cm, 14cm and 7.5cm." Is this sentence correct or should we use 'the' instead of 'a' because we have specified/defined the triangle by specifying its sides(with the help of a relative pronoun)?

Comment: Actually, either could be used.

Answer (score 3):

Use of the article 'a' is correct because when *triangle* is used, it hasn't been previously introduced; the specification follows after the subject.

The sentence is wrong, though, because of number: "whose side is 3cm, 14cm and 7.5cm." wrong because there are three sides (and three measurements).  "whose sides are..." would be correct.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "a" is correct. It's a random triangle which you see for the first time, it was never mentioned before in any **context**. There can be many triangles with these sides (yes, I understand it's unique "mathematically speaking", but not when talking about grammar)

However, I feel like you're confusing this with a different scenario where using "the" with this logic is OK: if this were a unique and famous triangle that everyone knows, just like saying "Who's **the** actor that played in "Once Upon a Time... in Hollywood", the one with the Italian surname?". Same case: using "that" (or a relative "who") with "the", and not "a".

Also, as @mgkrebbs mentioned, writing "side" here is wrong, because the question is talking about 3 sideS. If "side" were correct, then I could say something (silly) like: "My child is 2, 5 and 13 years old" :)
Obviously, you'd say "my children are".

Comment: Thanks for replying. Now i do understand the difference.